# How to set IDs based on a variable?

Tags: jquery, pug

I want to use `x` jQuery actions on `x` number of selectors, based on a variable `x`. Each jQuery action should happen for one single selector.

My Jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#less").click(function () {
        $("'#industry'+x,#less").hide();
    });
});
```

My pug code is:

```
-for (x in c){
    p(id="industry"+"x") If you click on "Less" button,I will disappear. 
    p#less Less
-}
```

I've also tried placing the script inside the loop. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you don't do this. Using incremental id attributes is an anti-pattern which leads to unnecessarily verbose code and maintenance problems later on. A better approach would be to give all the relevant elements a common class, then access them by index if you need a specific instance, eg `$('.industry').eq(x).hide()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you hide the text by getting the text relative to the #less link

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#less").click(function () {
             $(this).prev('[id^="industry"]').hide();
             $(this).hide();
     });
  });
```

Comment: I had to modify a bit but it was really helpful, works now. Thank you so much.